# Convert a String to Object (json) MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I am trying to execute the below command

```
function(field) {

   //field = '{"'+field+'":{$exists:true}}'; Not working
   //field = tojson(field) Not working
   //field = {"events.concessionDetails":{$exists:true}}; Works if passed as input param


    print(field);
    var cur = db.cssCases.aggregate([

    {$match:{"events.eventType" : {$nin:["FAIL_SYSTEM_SERVICE_CALL"]}}},

    { $unwind: "$events" },

    {$match:field},

    {$group:{_id:{eventType:"$events.eventType"}}},

    { $limit : 100 }

    ])
}
```

if I pass the below value for the field it works fine.

```
var field1 = {"events.concessionDetails":{$exists:true}};
```

But I dont want to pass the `'{$exists:true}'` and just want to pass `events.concessionDetails` and form the full command, Below is some code which I would like to execute to accomplish this task.

I tried the following with no success,

tojson(field)
tojsonObject(field)
eval(field)

Is there any way that we can use to convert a input string to json query to use it in query.

Comment: The first line won't work cos you convert it into a string literal instead of a JS primative (a.k.a an Object), try something like (without testing this one bit) `var field = {""+field+"": {$exists: true}}`

Comment: @Sammaye: The escape character is \ in Javascript, we tried it and we tried yours as well, its working.

Comment: So it is working now?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the `{$exists: true}` part in your function code ?

Something like :

```
var field = "events.concessionDetails" // function argument

var match = {
    $match: {}
}
match.$match[field] = { exists: true }
```

Then use the `match` variable when you call the aggregate method.